# Longest Substring Containing K Distinct Characters

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on the task to get the longest substring with k distinct characters.

**Example:**

input : abcbdbdbbdcdabd.

```
For k = 2, o/p is ‘bdbdbbd’
For k = 3, o/p is ‘bcbdbdbbdcd’
For k = 5, o/p is ‘abcbdbdbbdcdabd’
```

Here is my code is taken from [this site](https://www.techiedelight.com/find-longest-substring-containing-k-distinct-characters/):

```
// Define the character range
public static final int CHAR_RANGE = 128;

// Function to find the longest substring of a given string containing
// `k` distinct characters using a sliding window
public static String findLongestSubstring(String str, int k)
{
    // base case
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return str;
    }

    // stores the longest substring boundaries
    int end = 0, begin = 0;

    // set to store distinct characters in a window
    Set<Character> window = new HashSet<>();

    // Count array `freq` stores the frequency of characters present in the
    // current window. We can also use a map instead of a count array.
    int[] freq = new int[CHAR_RANGE];

    // `[low…high]` maintains the sliding window boundaries
    for (int low = 0, high = 0; high < str.length(); high++)
    {
        window.add(str.charAt(high));
        freq[str.charAt(high)]++;

        // if the window size is more than `k`, remove characters from the left
        while (window.size() > k)
        {
            // If the leftmost character's frequency becomes 0 after
            // removing it in the window, remove it from the set as well
            if (--freq[str.charAt(low)] == 0) {
                window.remove(str.charAt(low));
            }

            low++;        // reduce window size
        }

        // update the maximum window size if necessary
        if (window.size() ==k && end - begin < high - low)
        {
            end = high;
            begin = low;
        }
    }

    // return the longest substring found at `str[begin…end]`
    return str.substring(begin, end + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str = "abcbdbdbbdcdabd";
    int k = 2;

    System.out.print(findLongestSubstring(str, k));
}
```

Now my question is, in above code we have a while loop, `while (window.size() > k)`, I see that we can replace with just an `if` condition like `if(window.size() > k)`. I am not sure if I am correct here to change from while to if. As per the code we are adding a chaarcter to the window in for loop, and immediately checking if the window exceeds k, so a simple if condition should work. Is there any reason to use a while loop here.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Changing the `while` to `if` will have no impact on the correctness of the answer or on the asymptotic complexity of the code.

This pattern of `while` and `if` both working is very often true for these sliding window problems, where you're trying to find the longest substring/subarray satisfying some condition. Keeping it as a `while` makes the code much easier to reason about or prove correct: you get nice loop invariants, like 'at the end of each iteration of the loop, 'low' is the smallest value such that `str[low,...,high]` contains at most `k` distinct characters'. You also get the nice property that `window.size` is only ever at most `k+1`, and at most `k` at the end of each loop.

Changing the `while` to `if` seems like a 'clever' optimization: it still works (for this exact problem), and based on a naive 'operations performed' count, it does less total work. On the other hand, the code becomes more brittle, less general, and much harder to reason about: What are your loop invariants now that `window.size` can be as large as your alphabet? Now, the easiest way to prove correctness is by switching to an argument by contradiction, showing that if there is a longer valid substring, your sliding window cannot pass over it without finding it. Also, if you swap from strings to arrays of integers, the space complexity can get worse.

If you actually time the code, you might observe that the performance can actually get worse with the `if`, despite performing less work. On modern processors, cache locality and predictability is far more important than small constant factors: For example, doing 1000 repetitions of `hashset.remove()` in a tight while loop, can, unintuitively, be much faster than doing only 900 `hashset.remove()`, spread out over a longer period and with other operations mixed in between. As always, benchmark both versions, but be aware of the spacing of your data structure operations causing unexpected performance spikes.

Of course, it's important to know why using `if` gives the longest substring just as `while` does, and be able to prove that; however I'd recommend to avoid, unless truly necessary, these clever optimization tricks that offer hypothetical performance gains at the cost of simplicity and obvious correctness of the algorithm.